# Composer error when trying to install elfinder-laravel

Tags: php, composer-php, elfinder

I tried to install Laravel-elfinder in Laravel 5. In it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) 
there is a step by step tutorial that I've followed  but it is not working.

I have XAMPP web server on my Windows PC with Windows 8.

Basically I am going to my project folder and execute

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-elfinder
```

After a few seconds I got this error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\edent>composer require barryvdh/laravel-elfinder
Using version 0.3.* for barryvdh/laravel-elfinder
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-elfinder v0.3.0 requires barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driv
er 0.1.x@dev -> satisfiable by barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver[0.1.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-elfinder v0.3.1 requires barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driv
er 0.1.x@dev -> satisfiable by barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver[0.1.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-elfinder v0.3.2 requires barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driv
er 0.1.x@dev -> satisfiable by barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver[0.1.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-elfinder v0.3.3 requires barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driv
er 0.1.x@dev -> satisfiable by barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver[0.1.0].
    - barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver 0.1.0 requires intervention/image ~2.0
-> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.1
3, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.0.16, 2.0.17, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0
.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3].
    - intervention/image 2.1.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.1.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.1.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.1.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.9 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.8 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.7 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.6 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.5 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.4 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.17 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.16 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.15 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.14 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.13 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.12 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.11 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.10 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP ext
ension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-elfinder 0.3.* -> satisfiable by
 barryvdh/laravel-elfinder[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

All public packages that you install through composer are "searchable" in [packagist.org](https://packagist.org). So, if you search for laravel-elfinder in packagist, you'll end up [at this page](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder).

There, you'll see a list of **Requires**, which means that the package you're seeing depends on another package and you won't be able to use the one you want until you install those dependencies. However, since [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is really smart it will try to resolve those dependencies for you.

In your case, Composer resolves as much as it can. Basically, *[barryvdh/laravel-elfinder](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder)* depends on *[barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver)* which, in turn, depends on *[intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image)*. If you go to the later package, you'll see the list of Requires as such:

> **Requires**
>   php: >=5.3.0
>   ext-fileinfo: *

I've written all this so you can understand why, in your message dump, you see multiple messages stating

> intervention/image 2.1.3 **requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.**

Basically, what this means is that you need to enable the extension *fileinfo* in your PHP installation.

First, open your `php.ini` and check that you don't have the extension commented. Look for something like this:

```
#[PHP_FILEINFO]
#extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

If you find it, uncomment (remove the `#`) and restart your XAMPP.

If you don't, you'll need the file `php_fileinfo.dll` (which you can get in the [PHP For Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/) download page) from the `.zip` file that matches you PHP installation and you'll find the file in the `ext` folder.

Copy that file into your extensions folder, edit your `php.ini` and add this

```
[PHP_FILEINFO]
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Restart your XAMPP and you're done.

When you have the extension installed, run the `composer` command again.